# Brasero not working in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, brasero

I just upgraded to 18.04 and now Brasero not loading. I am not very computer savvy. So please make it simple. Thanks

Comment: What are the results of `type brasero` ?

Comment: Open a terminal and try to start it with `brasero` ; post the output.

Comment: It opens I add my files and when I try to burn it, it fails.

Comment: it opens and starts off fine when copying, but about 60% through it slows down. I mean it is crawling. Stops around 75% done.